# Linear Inequality Constraints not satisfied while using the GA. Premaure Convergence of the GA

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

My problem is a large size Mixed integer programming problem with some variables binary and others continuous. My code does not have any non-linear constraints or equality constraints. Still the GA is violating the Linear Inequalty constraints.

My script always return error

```
Optimization terminated: average change in the penalty fitness value less than options.TolFun
but constraints are not satisfied.
```

I have tried to implement the code for small size problems but still it violates the constraints. In some cases the ans is very much near to the global optimum value but even less than that for minimisation problem, which is a strict no no.

In other cases it just converges prematurely. I feed the linprog function solution of the problem to the ga as the Feasible Initial population.

Please Suggest me the corrections to be made.